# How to recursively/iteratively free all nodes of my data structure?

Tags: c, recursion, tree, tree-traversal

```
typedef struct              s_path
{
    struct s_path           *next;
    struct s_path           *leaf;
    struct s_path           *root;
    char                    *path;
    t_files_attrib          *attrib;
    }                       t_path;
typedef struct              s_files_attrib
{
    struct s_files_attrib   *next;
    struct s_files_attrib   *previous;

    char                    *filename;
    time_t                  timestamp;
    char                    permissions;
    char                    *owner_name;
    char                    *group_name;
    size_t                  file_size;
    size_t                  link_count;
    unsigned int            filetype;
    t_bool                  is_soft_link;
    char                    *link_pointer;
}                           t_files_attrib;
```

I have 2 structures and i have fuction to free  `t_files_attrib` list from it's beginning.
First structure implements file system tree.
[Example of tree starting from /](https://www.draw.io/?lightbox=1&highlight=0000ff&edit=_blank&layers=1&nav=1&title=fs_tree#R5VnLcpswFP0aL9PhYRS8TBy7nWk77YwXbbPJyEYGWoGIEDb06yssiYdxXFKnEUw2tnR09Tr3JYmJPY%2Fy9xQmwWfiITyxDC%2Bf2HcTy7qe2fy3BAoBmKYxFYhPQ09iNbAKfyMJGhLNQg%2BlLUFGCGZh0gY3JI7RhrUwSCnZt8W2BLdnTaCPOsBqA3EX%2FRZ6LBCo6xg1%2FgGFfsCq%2FcmWCCphCaQB9Mi%2BAdmLiT2nhDBRivI5wiV5ihfRb%2FlEa7UwimLWp8P9l%2FXjPcBWtPj48GttuWSxy6%2BkMlJWqA0jj%2B9fVgllAfFJDPGiRm8pyWIPlaMavBawCPOiyYs%2FEWOFVCHMGOFQPcInQhIpJ%2BYsJ3pyKxJKSUY36Mz6lUlA6iN2Rs6uCOeWikiEGC14P4owZOGuvQ4oTcav5GpWeUES%2BwyS5bg7iDM508QCmC%2F3dkv4hpv0g8eMqIar9EDlDRfg5OR1Iy%2F54n%2BpBuJFMZZqOdYqxtxjSu3tg5ChVQIPtO6507Z1CNNEuNE2zEsdy6F2iDKUn1dXl17ZYWo5oosKAspH9g2PklDQcCaFvbhCrkdu9XZPqwcXWv2h6w2lsGgIJCSMWdoY%2BWsJNLQN2tq2p0dx6UjeVgHytDwviBXU6q62coFLgjdiAqajM%2FJZY88vvWnWybJ9Ir8sPbQbdhaoDka6soA6Yo7WOEFP43S1hoCxR9q%2BLF96xPynZPuX5Pnc5Px%2Fki3oxCeuRLNrFjqjUxVmJDHTme7odIKgUfmN29NvZjqjkzsC05waAzPN2QhIc6yBkWa%2B6KWTs0CL783Kj1LonaOqd7nsJGqFrOl4onFeKYFedkyxRh5ue9Nsag24apnty8o6jNVL1poO8xELmO2Aov36Yo39gGDOelps47lcR2Sw3wrPet%2BKzO6xYpMMKwY44Oi2BXTHAKPDmbcdFmfAfTXOeLX%2BnCYur%2FVHSXvxBw%3D%3D).
Tree's leaf is chained list, which stores all files in this folder. If file is not a folder or empty folder it has no leaf.
How must i traverse this structure to free it?
Or how can i refactor code to make tree having various amount of leafs?
for example i have such folders

```
tests/
├── 123456789111111111111111111111
├── 12345678911111111111111111111111111
├── 12345678911111111111111111111111111111111
├── a
├── ls_out
├── test-fld1
│   ├── a
│   ├── b
│   └── c
└── test-fldr2



   void ft_path_append_vertical(t_path *pre, char *name)
    {
        t_path *path;

        path = malloc(sizeof(t_path *));
        path->root = pre;
        path->next = NULL;
        path->path = name;
        path->root = path;
        if (pre)
            pre->leaf = path;
    }
t_path *ft_path_append_horizontal(t_path *node, char *dat)
{
    t_path *nt;

    nt = malloc(sizeof(t_path *));
    if (dat)
        nt->path = ft_strdup(dat);
    nt->next = 0x0;
    if (!node)
        return (nt);
    node->next = nt;
    return (nt);
}
```

so my structure will be looked like this:

```
tests->leaf=123456789111111111111111111111;
123456789111111111111111111111->leaf = 12345678911111111111111111111111111;
.
.
.
test-fld1->leaf = a;
a->root = test-fld1;
a->next=b;
b->next=c;
c->next = NULL;
```

Comment: You should show the code that fills your data structure or even better write some simple code that creates a small example data structure with fixed example data.

Comment: @Bodo updated post

Comment: It is still not completely clear. Maybe you should list for your example file system tree how `ft_path_append_vertical` and `ft_path_append_horizontal` get called for all the files and directories.

Comment: it seems `t_path` represents a directory and `t_files_attrib` a file no ? If yes you can already represents your example of tree

Comment: If your object is a tree, do a post-order traversal: free its children before freeing the node itself.

Comment: @bruno thank you guys, your questions helped me to find a stupid mistake, and know what to do now.

Comment: @Vladimir am I right about the role of the structs ?

Comment: @bruno yap, and i accidentally mixed up structures

Comment: @Vladimir are you interrested by a full program to create/modify/print the tree starting from your example ?

Comment: @bruno i'm implementing ls program and i should go through this way alone

Comment: @Vladimir ok, have a pleasant dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you has the free function for t_files_attrib. Assumed it is 
 named **free_files_attrib**. I think use it before free the node.
You can define a function called fr_free for free all nodes with the input is the root of the tree. And we can do the free mechanism is similar to post-order free mechanism.

```
void ft_free(t_path *root)
{
    if (root == NULL) return;
    ft_free(root->leaf);
    ft_free(root->next);
    if (root->leaf == NULL && root->next == NULL) 
    {
        free_files_attrib(root->attrib);
        free(root);
        root = NULL;
        return;
    }       
}
```

For using it, you can call ft_free on **test** pointer. Assumed **test** is the root of your environment.

```
ft_free(test);
```

Comment: Where is `root` freed, if `->leaf` and/or `->next` is _not_ NULL?

Comment: @Ctx Yes, moved the root after call root->leaf and root->next. Thanks

Comment: It still leaks memory... `free(root)` has to be called unconditionally below.

Comment: I see a lot of memory leaks through the list of `t_files_attrib`

Comment: @bruno Semantics may be different here, just because the tree is freed doesn't mean, that the data has to be freed, too. It might still be referenced elsewhere

Comment: @Ctx hard links also exist about directories ^^

Comment: @bruno based on how he initilized *attrib property inside struct t_path, I don't see him use malloc to allocate memory in heap. I mean it depends on his context.

Comment: But you are _still_ leaking memory here (is it really so hard?). I wonder who still votes this up...

Comment: @Ctx `t_files_attrib` has next and prev pointers to other `t_files_attrib` exactly like `t_path` has next pointer to other `t_path`, so if there is no _malloc_ for `t_files_attrib`  how can you suppose there is _malloc_ for `t_path` ? What I miss ?

Comment: @bruno I didn't say that, but the `malloc()` for t_path is visible above in the code. The other is not. But that's not _my_ point anyway, the point is: the `t_files_attrib` in the tree might still be referenced elsewhere, so it might be a _bug_ to free it together with the tree. We do not know that and can only hope, that the OP knows, how to handle this part of the structure. _This_ function here only frees the metadata of the data structure.

Comment: @bruno, Vladimir has a function to free the t_files_attrib already, I think we should use it for free this stuff before free the node

Comment: What is the purpose of the `if (root->leaf == NULL && root->next == NULL)` test?

Comment: to follow IanAbbott ,  what are the purpose of `root = NULL;` and the return just after ? I really do not understand how it was possible to upvote and choose that  answer ^^

Comment: @bruno Exactly! It looks like the code is assuming that C supports call-by-reference parameters, which of course it doesn't.

Comment: I added root = NULL; for avoiding the dangling pointer problem

Comment: and you added the `return` to be sure to exit the function ? ... ok easy joke ^^

Comment: @bruno agreed. something is so carefully made a joke.